# To talk angrily and provoked in a low voice

Tags: verbs, nouns, adjectives

I'm looking for a word that can describe a person continuously talking angrily as if fighting with someone, for example over a phone, but in a low and whispering manner.

Comment: Growling. e.g. "Stop that!" he growled.

Comment: That's good, more in a continuous fashion.

Comment: "Stop that, you i--di-ot!" he growled in syncopated whisper.

Comment: How about simply, "Nathan could overhear a man at the other end of the bar arguing with someone on the phone in an *angry whisper*."

Comment: That's an option undoubtedly, I just thought there might be a word that can specifically describe that.

Comment: AnotherGuest you have asked twelve questions so far but accepted only one answer. Please remember to accept the answer which you found helped you the most. Not only will users feel a warm fuzzy glow in their hearts because their answers have been useful, but you will gain reputation points as well.

Comment: He "spoke like Batman" over the phone.

Comment: @WS2 criticism annotated but my point remains valid.

Comment: *Speak softly and carry a big stick.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already noted you could use *[growl](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/growl)*:-

> v.intr.
>   1. To emit a low guttural sound or utterance.
>   2. To speak in an angry or surly manner.

or possibly *[snarl](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snarl)*:-

> v.intr.
>   1. To growl viciously while baring the teeth.
>   2. To speak angrily or threateningly.

or perhaps *[hiss](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Hiss)*:-

> 1. A sharp sibilant sound similar to a sustained s.
> 2. An expression of disapproval, contempt, or dissatisfaction conveyed by use of this sound.
>
> v.tr.
>   1. To utter with a hiss:
>   2. To express (a negative view or reaction) by uttering a hiss: The audience hissed its displeasure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of 'a malevolent undertone'. It sounds more sinister than an 'angry growl'.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *mutter*.  It combines connotations of both anger and low volume in a way that isn't true of *growl*.